# mysql 'WHERE' with 500 'OR's?

Tags: php, mysql

Is it ok to have a WHERE statement with a lot of OR's? I imagine the most could ever be 500.

I am dealing with a facebook app. Understandably (but annoyingly) they do not allow app developers to store friend relationships. As a result I can not do a sensible JOIN tblfriend or something along those lines.

To get a list of friends you can query facebook using FQL... that will return an array of facebook user ids. My thinking was to find a users most recent friend I could run a query like this:

```
'SELECT * FROM user WHERE fb_id = ' . implode('OR fb_id = ', $friend_array) . ' ORDER BY created LIMIT 0,1';
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Couldn't you use IN instead? Have a look at this tutorial: http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tutorials/sql/tutorial_mysql_in_and_between.php3

Comment: Thank you Lazaurus... you were first :) - also your tutorial taught be about BETWEEN... thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Marek Karbarz said, use IN :

```
'SELECT * FROM user WHERE fb_id IN (' . implode(',', $friend_array) . ') ORDER BY created LIMIT 0,1';
```

Answer (score 5):

you could use an `IN` clause

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN contruct.

```
..WHERE fb_id IN (1,2,3)
```

is the same as

```
..WHERE fb_id = 1 OR fb_id = 2 OR fb_id = 3
```